# WooCommerce - Make shipping address default store address

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am wanting to make the default shipping address on WooCommerce the same as the store address. There is no solution for reverse logistics and this seems the quickest way around it. Customers pay to ship their items to us which in turn is sent directly to our courier where they can print off shipping labels.

I found [Assign Dokan vendor shipping address to store address in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605849/assign-dokan-vendor-shipping-address-to-store-address-in-woocommerce/53606506#53606506) related answer by @LoicTheAztec, but it does not seem to be working so I am a little stuck.

---

**Edit**

I spoke too soon, I got it to work removing `current_user_can( 'vendor' )` from all `IF` statements. Thank you @LoicTheAztec

Comment: Absolutely, thank you.